# Navigating Wordpress Articles From Parent Category?

Tags: navigation

Good day, please tell me how to fix the navigation in the parent category.
For example:

Parent Category - News - Subsidiaries (Company News and Market News)
Pagination now works within the category, and how to do something you can scroll within (Company News and Market News), that is, throughout the parent category!

```php
next_post_link ('<div class="nav-next"> %link', '<span class="nav-subtitle"></span><span class="nav-title">%title</span></div>', true);
previous_post_link('<div class="nav-previous"> %link', '<span class="nav-subtitle"></span><span class="nav-title">%title</span></div>', true);
```

Comment: I've edited the formatting but I still do not understand the question, it doesn't make sense. Can you change the words and explain clearer so that it can be understood?

Comment: have you read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/ ? have you tried to remove the 'true' from both function calls?

Comment: News - parent category
     Company News - child category
     Market News  - child category
How fix navigation Company News  and  Market News  - navigate from  category  where parent  News